# tictactoe function doesn't take input values

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm trying to write a function that finds winner status of tictactoe. But, I have an mistake I can't find it. When i paste input values by console, it closes the terminal and doesn't take last part of inputs(O X O). Could you tell me where my wrong is ? Thank you for all appreciated answers.
Example in put is:

```
3
X
X O X
X X X
O X O
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

char result(char board[][3]);
void test_part1();


int main(){

    test_part1();

    return 0;
}
char result(char board[][3]){

    char winner = 'T';
    int i;

// Checks for:
//     X X X
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if (//bla bla)
        return winner;
        }

// Checks for:
// X
// X
// X
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                if (//bla bla)
                return winner;
        }

// Checks for:
// X                 X
//   X      or     X
//     X         X
    if (//bla bla)
            return winner;
        }
            return winner;
}
void test_part1(){

    int size;
    char ch;
    int i,j;
    char tictac[3][3];

    scanf("%d",&size);
        if(size==3){
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        scanf("%c",&tictac[i][j]);
    if(ch==(result(tictac)))
        printf("Win\n");
    else if('T'==(result(tictac)))
        printf("Draw\n");
    else
        printf("Lost\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Size is must be 3\n");
        return;
    }


}
```

Comment: wow thank you i didn't know it. Do we always put the space to skip whitespaces like " %c" or like "%c " ? @user3121023

Comment: the correct method of skipping white space is " %c", I.E. the space first.

Comment: since the size of a tictac board is always 3x3, why bother to request such size from the user?

Comment: since size is ALWAYS 3, you could avoid the overhead of referencing a variable from the stack (I.E. bury the small const inside the code instructions) by replacing all references to 'size' with '3' and eliminating the variable size and the extra interaction with the user

Comment: i dont know logic of the assignment if i write regard to my idea it would be different but it is homework and instructor gives the prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space before `%c` in both the `scanf`s so that they look like this:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
scanf(" %c",&tictac[i][j]);
```

This is done to skip the newline character(`\n` or the enter key) which you press after entering data for the `scanf`. `\n` will still be present in the input buffer which will be taken by the next `scanf` with a `%c`,and thus will not wait for you to enter anything . The space before `%c` will discard all blanks(spaces,newlines etc).

Comment: Do we always put the space like `" %c"` ? Can we put like `"%c "` ? I'm asking for not the question, in general ?

Comment: You need to discard the `\n` **before** scanning the next character otherwise ,`%c` will get the `\n`. So,`" %c"` is correct

Answer (score 0):

With the size of the tictac grid always being 3x3 suggest the following:

Note: this algorithm does not differentiate as to which player is to play next nor if the input is to be an `'x'` or an `'o'`.  This algorithm does not allow the player(s) to choose which square in the 3x3 grid is to receive their input.

I suggest modifying the algorithm to have two players (one could be the computer) and enable the (current) player to place their marker where they want it.

```
void test_part1()
{

    char ch; // input value from user
    int i;   // loop counter
    int j;   // loop counter
    char tictac[3][3];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if( 1 != scanf(" %c",&tictac[i][j]) )
            {
                 handle error and exit
            }

            // implied else

           if(ch==(result(tictac)))
           {
               printf("Win by &c\n", ch);
           }

           else if('T'==(result(tictac)))
           {
               printf("Draw\n");
           }
           else
           {
               printf("Lost\n");
           } // end if-else
       } // end for()
   } // end for()

}
```